# Display Format String to User

Tags: c#, data-annotations, string-formatting

How do I go about displaying a format string as-is?

I have a property decorated with some data annotations:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public blah blah { get; set; }
```

I now have a reference to the format string:

```
string format = metadata.DisplayFormatString; // == {0:MM/dd/yyyy}
```

I want to display this format string to the user without manually typing it in my view. Is there a nice way (not replace chars with empty string) to get `MM/dd/yyyy` from the string `format`?

Comment: Why not replace chars? Surely that's what any other method would do anyway? I suppose you could use a regular expression, but that will be very similar.

Comment: Because I have several different format strings. Some of them contain colons and such that should be displayed and I was hoping there was a generic way to do it to where I don't have to worry about escaped chars and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing using replace is a nice way too. If you're concerned about clutter in the view, you could put this into an extension method (or even an HTML Helper extension method).

```
public static string ToUserFriendlyDateFormat(this string unfriendlyFormat) {
    return unfriendlyFormat
        .Replace("{0:", string.Empty)
        .Replace("}", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Since there's no generic way to handle it, I went with a simple replace that has the cases for my different format strings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all your format strings look like, but if your format strings ever make it to String.Format() you already have to escape { and } characters (by doubling them).  How about using a regular expression.  Here's something simple to start with that will also undouble the { and } characters:

```
string DisplayFormat(string format) {
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"\{\d+:([^}]+)}|\{\{|}}");
    return rx.Replace(format, delegate(Match m) {
        if (m.Value == "{{") {
            return "{";
        } else if (m.Value == "}}") {
            return "}";
        } else {
            return m.Groups[1].Value;
        }
    });
}
```

Note that the above code will have to change if your format strings contain sequences like `{0}` and you want something special done with them as well.